# Rails - Reducing queries using includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

This is my controller:

```rb
@trainings = Training.includes(:courses).order(:id, 'courses.order_id ASC')
```

In my view, for each training I need to loop for 3 times and check if has a course with column order_id with these values:

```rb
@trainings.each do |training|
    for course_order in (1..3) do
        this_course = training.courses.find_by(order_id: course_order)
        # this_course.image(:resized) #i can print the paperclip image
    end
end
```

The code **above** executes so many queries, so I tried using `select` method:

```rb
@trainings.each do |training|
    for course_order in (1..3) do
        this_course = training.courses.select { |course| course.order_id = course_order }
        # this_course.image(:resized) #I cannot print paperclip image, because the result is an Array, so doesn't know the method "image"
    end
end
```

So I have just one query, but I cannot call the image method from my Model, because the result is an Array object.

I know I can use:

```rb
training.courses.each do |course|
    # course.image(:resized)
end
```

and I will get just one query, but I must loop 3 times, so when I dont have the row I can print a placeholder image, like:

[Example image http://www.onrails.com.br/order_id.jpg](http://www.onrails.com.br/order_id.jpg)

Comment: `order_id` can only be between 1 and 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your

```
this_course = training.courses.find_by(order_id: course_order)
```

returns first record that matches conditions, but

```
this_course = training.courses.select { |course| course.order_id == course_order }
```

selects all courses that match condition. If you want to find only the first one, use [`.detect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-detect) instead of [`.select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-select):

```
this_course = training.courses.detect { |course| course.order_id == course_order }
```

Also you have a typo. `=` is for assignment, `==` is for comparing.

Comment: I think using detect I'll always get a result, including that doesn't matches. This was my result: [IMAGE](http://www.onrails.com.br/detect.jpg).

Comment: @LuizGustavoF.Gama see updated answer. You always get a result, because of `=`. Change it to `==`.